# Обособленное приложение или сравнение со значением "в качестве"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

В начале 2000-х годов «теплый пол», как бытовой товар, в России был в диковинку.

Сама думаю, что запятые не требуются, так как дополнительного обстоятельственного значения нет.

Comment: Тёплые полы не требуют кавычек. Лишнее и слово «годов».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В начале 2000-х годов теплый пол **как бытовой товар** в России был в диковинку.

Да, оборот со значением "в качестве" не обособляется. Теплый пол можно не заключать в кавычки, так как сейчас это общеизвестный термин.